# I want highlight the color when the button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, button, wpf-controls, background-color

In my form i am having six buttons,i want highlight the color when the button is clicked,after the another button clicked the previous button should background color should change to its native color,now selected button should highlight in WPF using C#

```
   private void btn_dailysales_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_dailysales.Background = Brushes.DarkSlateGray;
    }

    private void btn_dailysales_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: @Homer_J i have tried in mouse leave and mouse enter events,when mouse out i dont how to write the code to change its own color

Comment: Could you update your question with your code/ code examples of what you have tried, so we can see?

Comment: i want in untill the next button clicked the button remains in highlighted color only...

Comment: Are you sure you need buttons? This sounds like RadioButtons to me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use RadioButton. Look [here](http://wpfstyles.blogspot.it/2011/09/beautify-your-radiobuttons.html) for some very good examples:

http://wpfstyles.blogspot.it/2011/09/beautify-your-radiobuttons.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to visualize what button was pressed last you need to have something common to the group of buttons.

I would create a container/panel to group the buttons and preview the click on a button in the panel. The panel should then send out to all the buttons a signal that they should reset their styles, handle the click of the button and change its style to highlighting.

Alternatively, If you are trying to switch one thing on out of a group it would be an option to use RadioButtons instead. All you would have to do is set the checked/unchecked styles of the radio buttons.